# Split string into possible combinations AA-200A/B/C or ranges AA-100 to 105

Tags: string, vb.net, split

I have strings (they are actually part numbers) in text files that have not been entered correctly (in full).  I need to split and then concatenate them to represent the full part number.

For example:
String **ZVN-798-100A/B/C** should have been entered as:

- ZVN-798-100A
- ZVN-798-100B
- ZVN-798-100C

String **XPD-279-100 to 103** should have been entered as:

- XPD-279-100
- XPD-279-101
- XPD-279-102
- XPD-279-103

My code splits these correctly:

- AA-10-100A/B/C
- BB-20-100A to C
- DD-40-100 / 110 / 120
- EE-50-100A~H

But not these:

- CC-30-100 thru 105
- FF-60-110 to 15

For simplicity of posting to SO I have created a single sub of my code:

```
Private Sub btnRun_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click

    Dim arrSplitEach(2) As String
    arrSplitEach(0) = "\"
    arrSplitEach(1) = "/"
    arrSplitEach(2) = ","

    Dim arrSplitAll(2) As String
    arrSplitAll(0) = " to "
    arrSplitAll(1) = " thru "
    arrSplitAll(2) = "~"

    Dim strFromFile(5) As String
    strFromFile(0) = "AA-10-100A/B/C"
    strFromFile(1) = "BB-20-100A to C"
    strFromFile(2) = "CC-30-100 thru 15"
    strFromFile(3) = "DD-40-100 / 110 / 120"
    strFromFile(4) = "EE-50-100A~H"
    strFromFile(5) = "FF-60-100 to 115"

    Dim arrOutput As New ArrayList

    Dim iSplitEach As Integer
    Dim iSplitAll As Integer

    Dim strSplitter As String

    rtbOutput.Clear()
    rtbOutput.Update()

    For iString As Integer = LBound(strFromFile) To UBound(strFromFile)

        Dim s As String = strFromFile(iString).ToString.Trim

        If s <> "" Then

            For iSplitEach = LBound(arrSplitEach) To UBound(arrSplitEach)
                strSplitter = arrSplitEach(iSplitEach).ToString

                If s.Contains(strSplitter) Then
                    Dim parts As Array = Replace(s, " ", "").Split(strSplitter)
                    Dim derived As New List(Of String)

                    derived.Add(parts(0))

                    Dim intLoopParts As Integer
                    For intLoopParts = 1 To parts.Length - 1
                        If Not Len(parts(intLoopParts)) = 0 And Not parts(0).Length < Len(parts(intLoopParts)) Then
                            derived.Add(parts(0).Remove(parts(0).Length - Len(parts(intLoopParts))) & parts(intLoopParts))
                        End If
                    Next

                    For Each strPart As String In derived
                        'If strNotVerifiedSplit.Contains(strPart.ToLower.Trim) = False Then
                        If Not arrOutput.Contains(strPart.Trim) Then
                            arrOutput.Add(Replace(strPart.Trim, " ", ""))
                            strFromFile(iString).Equals(strFromFile(iString) & " | Split")
                        End If
                    Next

                    derived.Clear()

                End If
            Next iSplitEach

        For iSplitAll = LBound(arrSplitAll) To UBound(arrSplitAll)
            strSplitter = arrSplitAll(iSplitAll).ToString

            If s.Contains(strSplitter) Then

                Dim strMain As String = Replace(Strings.Left(s, InStr(s, strSplitter) - 1), " ", "")

                Dim strStart As String = Mid(s, InStr(s, strSplitter) - 1, 1)
                Dim strEnd As String = Strings.Right(s, 1)

                Dim strToPlace As String

                For Each c As Char In "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()
                    strToPlace = Strings.Left(strMain, Len(strMain) - 1) & c

                    If Not strToPlace = "" Then

                        If Not arrOutput.Contains(strToPlace.Trim) Then
                            arrOutput.Add(Replace(strToPlace, " ", ""))
                            strFromFile(iString).Equals(strFromFile(iString) & " | Split")
                        End If

                    End If

                    If c = strEnd Then
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next c

            End If
        Next iSplitAll
        End If
        s = ""
    Next iString

    For iOutput As Integer = 0 To arrOutput.Count - 1
        rtbOutput.SelectionStart = rtbOutput.TextLength
        rtbOutput.SelectionLength = 0

        If Not arrOutput(iOutput) = "" Then
            rtbOutput.AppendText(arrOutput(iOutput).Trim & vbCrLf)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I have found many articles about splitting strings, but do not see a duplicate to this specific case.

It seems like overkill to have to add another chunk of code just to deal with the number ranges and I hope someone can offer some wise advice to improve my existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this and avoid the VB6 code style:

```
Private fList() As String = {"\", "/", ","}
Private fRange() As String = {" to ", " thru ", "~"}
Private Const Letters As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

Private Function SplitParts(Part As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim S, Vals() As String
    For Each S In fList
        Vals = Split(Part, S)
        If Vals.Length > 1 Then Return FixList(Vals)
    Next
    For Each S In fRange
        Vals = Split(Part, S)
        If Vals.Length > 1 Then Return FixRange(Vals)
    Next
    Return {Part}
End Function

Private Function FixList(Vals() As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim Ret As New List(Of String), First, Suffix As String
    First = Vals.First.Trim
    Ret.Add(First)
    For i As Integer = 1 To Vals.Length - 1
        Suffix = Vals(i).Trim
        Ret.Add(First.Substring(0, First.Length - Suffix.Length) & Suffix)
    Next
    Return Ret
End Function

Private Function FixRange(Vals() As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim Range As New List(Of String), First, Last, Format As String, i, iMin, iMax As Integer
    First = Vals.First.Trim : Last = Vals.Last.Trim
    If Integer.TryParse(Last, iMax) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(First.Substring(First.Length - Last.Length), iMin) Then
        Format = New String("0"c, Last.Length)
        For i = iMin To iMax
            Range.Add(i.ToString(Format))
        Next
    ElseIf Last.Length = 1 Then
        iMin = Letters.IndexOf(First.Last) : iMax = Letters.IndexOf(Last)
        If iMin >= 0 AndAlso iMax >= 0 Then
            For i = iMin To iMax
                Range.Add(Letters(i))
            Next
        End If
    End If
    First = First.Substring(0, First.Length - Vals.Last.Trim.Length)    'Prefix
    Return Range.Select(Function(X) First & X)
End Function
```

Comment: That's excellent @PavlinII and certainly improves upon my existing code.  I am most grateful.  Out of interest, is there a way to export the 'FixRange>>Results' to an array where the value does not already exist in the array?

Comment: You can call .Distinct.ToArray on any IEnumerable (that means any array or any list). Or if you have some other list with values to avoid, you can add all to New HashSet(Of String) and then read the unique values (just call .ToArray)